# How can I fix my project after upgrading to Unity 2019 / .NET 4.x?

Tags: unity, .net

My Unity version was about a year out of date. After upgrading it to Unity 2019.1.5f1 through the Unity Hub, my project started throwing hundreds of errors. The most prominent one seemed to be:

```
Feature `out variable declaration' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 4.0 language specification
```

How can I fix my project so that it runs again?

Comment: When asking about a compiler error, it's usually good practice to include a snippet of the code responsible for the error.

Answer (score 2):

Go to **Edit** > **Project Settings** > **Player** and change the **Scripting Runtime Version** to `.NET 4.x Equivalent`.

Restart Unity and the project should compile again, unless you have other errors as well.

[image]